# FOSUserBundle login form not showing after extending layout.html.twig

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've read the guide and after installing, configuring and overriding the default template I can browse to my Login page but only my header and footer show up, there is no login form.

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: WX\ExchangeBundle\Entity\TblUser
```

routing.yml:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /Dashboard

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /SignUp

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /ResetPassword

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

security.yml:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /Login
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/Login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/SignUp, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ResetPassword, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/Confirm, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/Dashboard/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Controller:

```
namespace WX\ExchangeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/Login", name="wx_exchange_login")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig")
     * User log up - Open to public
     * Authenticates users to the system
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/Dashboard", name="wx_exchange_dashboard")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:user.html.twig")
     * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
     * Dashboard - secured for authenticated users
     * Determines if a user is logged in and redirects them to the user dashboard or login page
     */
    public function dashboardAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's not clear from the documentation if I'm supposed to return something in my Controller action. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by extending the login.html.twig file in my own login file:

`{% extends 'FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig' %}`

Answer (score 0):

You only need the block

```
{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

in your layout.html.yml, not in your base.html.yml.

Also you need to render the template with your return.

```
/**
 * @Route("/Login", name="wx_exchange_login")
 * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig")
 * User log up - Open to public
 * Authenticates users to the system
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    return $this->render('WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig');
}
```

instead of returning the array

Comment: Having only `{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}` in my layout.html.twig makes it so that my header/footer no longer display. Also according to the docs I'm doing it correctly so that I have my own custom content wrapping the FOSUserBundle login form. As for the render I'm using annotations so the line `@Template("WXExchangeBundle:User:login.html.twig")` does the template rendering and as I said I can see my head/footer. Further if I add some tags/content to the layout.html.twig it does show up on my Login page. Thanks but any more help?

Comment: On my page i render the LoginAction into my Layout so it's always visible where i want it. Maybe this helps you, you can do it with
`{% render controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:Login") %}`

Comment: I'd like to get it working as per the documentation if possible. That way I know it's working as expected. Thanks for your help.